# Selecting rows in groups with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

```
        A     B     C
0    blue  14.5  14.0
1    blue  14.0  14.0
2    blue  13.5  14.0
3    blue  12.0  14.0
4    blue  10.5  14.0
5   green  20.0  19.0
6   green  19.0  19.0
7   green  18.5  19.0
8   green  18.0  19.0
9   green  17.5  19.0
10  green  16.0  19.0
```

I want to create a new `df1` with next conditions, per each *A group* ("blue" and "green"):

- Select the rows where *B = C* and rows where *B = C-1*
- If it doesn´t exist any *B value* in the group that satisfy the condition *(B = C-1)*, select the next row further down that would correspond. For instance, in "blue group" *B = C - 1* would be *14.0 - 1 = 13.0* . As it doesn´t exist any `13.0` "blue group", select the next row further down that exists in `df`, that is:

  `3    blue  12.0  14.0`

df1 should be:

```
       A     B     C
1   blue  14.0  14.0
3   blue  12.0  14.0
6  green  19.0  19.0
8  green  18.0  19.0
```

I´ve tried:

```
df1 = df[(df["B"] == df["C"]) | (df["B"] == df["C"]-1)]
```

Comment: Would you care to better explain what this means `If (B = C-1) doesn´t exist in group, select the next further down row`

Comment: if in row `8` is changed `18.0` to `18.7` do you need select row `10` for group `green` ?

Comment: In that case, I´d need to select row 9 for group green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second condition: `B = C - 1`,

- we can set a condition `B - C <= -1` and then
- find the indices of the first row that satisfies this condition in each group.

  ```
  idx_cond = df.groupby("A").apply(
                 lambda x: x.where(x.B-x.C <= -1).first_valid_index())
  # A
  # blue     3
  # green    8
  # dtype: int64
  pd.concat([df[df.B == df.C], df.loc[idx_cond]])
  ```

Answer (score 1):

the conditions:

- `row where B = C - 1`
- `if not exists B = C - 1, then row with largest B, such that B < C - 1`

can be combined into 1 condition:

```
row with largest B, such that B <= C - 1
```

if your data is such that the first condition, i.e. `row where B = C` exists for all groups, then you can write the projection like this:

```
res = df[(df.B == df.C) | (df.B <= df.C - 1)].sort_values('B').groupby('A').tail(2)

# output:

       A     B     C
3   blue  12.0  14.0
1   blue  14.0  14.0
8  green  18.0  19.0
6  green  19.0  19.0
```

If the first condition, `B = C` doesn't match for some groups, then use pd.concat to union two separate projections:

```
res = pd.concat([df[df.B == df.C], 
                 df[df.B <= df.C - 1].sort_values('B').groupby('A').tail(1)])

# or you can split this long line into a couple of lines for better 
# readibility
# p1 = df[df.B == df.C]
# p2 = df[df.B <= df.C - 1].sort_values('B').groupby('A').tail(1)
# res = pd.concat([p1, p2])
# output:

       A     B     C
1   blue  14.0  14.0
6  green  19.0  19.0
3   blue  12.0  14.0
8  green  18.0  19.0
```

as you can see, with the 2nd solution the rows are not returned in the order you specify in the question, so a further multi-column sort may be necessary if you need ordered result:

```
res.sort_values(['C', 'B'], ascending=[True, False])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

- first create helper column `D` with `C` subtract by Counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) - get all possible values `B == C-0,1,2,3...`
- filter by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) per groups with `groupby`, remove column `D`
- if necessary sorting `A` and `B` by [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)
- filter first 2 rows per group by Counter with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

---

```
df['D'] = df['C'].sub(df.groupby('A').cumcount())
df = df[df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x['B'].isin(x['D'])).values].drop('D',1)
df = df.sort_values(['A','B'], ascending=[True, False])
df = df[df.groupby('A').cumcount() < 2]
print (df)
       A     B     C
1   blue  14.0  14.0
3   blue  12.0  14.0
6  green  19.0  19.0
8  green  18.0  19.0
```